# Background image overlapping character (love2d)

Tags: background, lua, layer, love2d

```
background = love.graphics.newImage ("joust.png")
  bird = love.graphics.newImage ("bird.png")
  x = 0
  y = 128
  speed = 300

  function love.update (dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown ("d") then
      x = x + (speed * dt)
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown ("a") then
      x = x - (speed * dt)
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown ("w") then
      y = y - (speed * dt)
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown ("s") then
      y = y + (speed * dt)
    end
  end

 function love.draw()
  love.graphics.draw(bird, x, y)
  for i = 0, love.graphics.getWidth() / background:getWidth() do
    for j = 0, love.graphics.getHeight() / background:getHeight() do
      love.graphics.draw(background, i * background:getWidth(), j * background:getHeight())
    end
  end
 end
```

Let me first start with I know this is a lot of code so I'm sorry. I'm trying to make a character moving with an image behind it as the background. when I run the program, what seems to happen is the background overlaps the character and you can't see the character. when I remove the background code the character appears and works as it should. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Much appreciated

Comment: sometimes it helps to take pen an paper and do the drawing steps in your code by hand. then  you will easily see that you paint your background over your bird which doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rearrange love.draw() function to paint bird after background:

```
 function love.draw()
  for i = 0, love.graphics.getWidth() / background:getWidth() do
    for j = 0, love.graphics.getHeight() / background:getHeight() do
      love.graphics.draw(background, i * background:getWidth(), j * background:getHeight())
    end
  end
  love.graphics.draw(bird, x, y)
 end
```